# TypeError : 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, integer, iteration, typeerror, python-3.7

I'm trying to preprocess video frames for anomaly event detection. The model is already trained but I can't figure out the issue with the following code (I'm a beginner). Please help with this respected developers.

```py
def Fit_Preprocessing(path: object, frames_ext: object) -> object:

    if frames_ext is None:
        raise TypeError(
            'Invalid Value for argument `frames_ext`, it cannot be None. Give proper extensions of the frames e.g: `.tif` or `.png` etc!')
    print('\n\nProcessing Images in this Dataset Path: {0}\n'.format(path))
    file_names: List[Union[str, List[str]]]
    onlyfiles, file_names, dirs = ReadFileNames(path, frames_ext)
    img_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    for img in tqdm(range(len(onlyfiles))):
        images = onlyfiles[img]
        count = 0
        for images in onlyfiles[img]:
            img.split('/')
            img_name = dirs[i] + '_' + file_names[i][count]
            write_path = 'ProcessedImages/' + path.split('/')[1]
            gray = ProcessImg(img_name, read_path=img, write=True,
                              write_path=write_path, res_shape=(227, 227))
            img_list.append(gray)
            count += 1
    return img_list
```

Getting this error:

```
Processing Images in this Dataset Path: C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Surveillance with deep learning/Datasets/UCSD_Anomaly_Dataset.v1p2/UCSDped1/Test

  0%|          | 0/47 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Surveillance-with-deep-learning/preprocessing.py", line 171, in <module>
    img_list: object = Fit_Preprocessing(path, frames_ext='.Fit')
  File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Surveillance-with-deep-learning/preprocessing.py", line 154, in Fit_Preprocessing
    for images in onlyfiles[img]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried using images = img_list to fix the loop but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an error is because in the for loop:

```py
for images in onlyfiles[img]:
```

You are getting the value using the index to access it, and `onlyfiles[img]` will, according to your code, return an `int` value. Since I don't know what you are clearly doing, my suggestion is to turn `onlyfiles[img]` into a `list`, so it iterates only through one thing or more, using:

```py
for images in [onlyfiles[img]]:
```

##### Example:

```py
my_int = 123
for i in my_int:
    print(i)
```

Gets the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    for i in my_int:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So if you turn it into a list:

```py
my_int = 123
for i in [my_int]:
    print(i)
```

Gives:

```
123
```

Or if you want to iterate through the digits, turn it into a string:

```py
my_int = 123
for i in str(my_int):
    print(i)
```

Gives:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I turned it into a list and now I am getting this error:    attributeError:  'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @StephenLongwe you may get better results by using the `range` function, so instead of `str(onlyfiles[img]):` you can try `range(onlyfiles[img]):`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range